# Showing that integral over emptyset is 0

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $\left(X,\mathcal{M},\mu\right)$ be a measure space. Let $g$ be a nonnegative function that is integrable over $X$. Define

$$v(E)=\int_{E}gd\mu,\text{ for all } E\in\mathcal{M}.$$

I'm trying to show that $v(\emptyset)=0$, and wondering if my approach is correct:

Since $g$ is a nonnegative measurable functions, by The Simple Approximation Theorem there is an increasing sequence $\{\phi_n\}$ of nonnegative simple functions on $X$ that converges pointwise on $X$ to $g$.

Therefore, by The Monotone Convergence Theorem,

$$v(E)=\int_{E}gd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E}\phi_nd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\phi_n\cdot\mu(E)\right).$$

Hence,

$$v(\emptyset) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\phi_n\cdot\mu(\emptyset)\right).$$

Since $\mu$ is a measure, $\mu(\emptyset)=0$. Therefore, it follows $v(\emptyset)=0$.

Comment: Or note that we must have $\int_{\emptyset\cup E}=\int_\emptyset+\int_E$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:That is pretty simple, but is my approach correct as well?